# When doing image transformation using fabric js, rounding box goes out of boders

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am creating a webpage, on that page i am trying to apply matrix transformation on image object. The transformation works but the rounding box didn't reset. when try to re size or rotate images the actual points are going out of image. here is my code.

```
var img22 = fabric.Image.fromURL('Test-img/Apron-001-449.jpg', function(oImg) {
    oImg.set({transformMatrix: [ 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0 ], width:200,height:300, top: 300, left: 250});
oImg.setCoords();
canvas1.add(oImg);

});
canvas1.renderAll();
```

can someone show me how to fix this problem

Comment: here is a fiddle of my problem  https://jsfiddle.net/ULsr4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known bug in fabric js version 1.4.0. Simply updating the library to version 1.5.0 fixes the problem. See fiddle with your `example` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ULsr4/22/)